# What type of security should I use in Spring REST application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring REST application, and I'm thinking about what type of security to use. I'm considering between two options:

1. Spring Security with OAuth2
2. Spring Security with JWT like here https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java
3. Any other option?

It must be good and secure enough for nowadays.
Application is going to be a simple service or few small services.
As a database I'm using MongoDB (probably it doesn't matter).

Maybe someone has some pros and cons of each type or any other suggestions what to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909419/jwt-vs-oauth-authentication

Answer (score 2):

First of all , your both points are same and point # 2 is incorrect as **JWT** is only a token format and not the actual security mechanism so both can't be compared.

**OAuth2** server is the one which will generate token for you either in JWT or non-JWT format , that is your choice.

I am not sure about all the technologies out there but if you go by popularity, an OAuth2 as Authorization Server and JWT as token format are quite popular.

Application / API Security means lots of things and **Authentication plus Authorization** prevents lots of attacks. Obviously, not everything is a developer concern and most goes to infrastructure or security teams.

### Flow

1. Set up an Authentication Mechanism
2. Set up an Authorization Mechanism ( OAuth2 ) connected to same User
   Source as Authentication mechanism. From here , you will get a token in JWT or non - JWT format. Getting token in JWT format has advantages that you can read on
3. Now you set up a mechanism in your API project ( Usually Filters ) to parse and validate JWT  token. Requests without valid tokens would be declined. This will force your clients to first authenticate themselves and retrieve a valid token to use your APIs.
4. You can set up few more security in your API using Spring Security like XSS attacks, Cross Domain etc