# JWT Authentication in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2, jjwt

I am new Spring Core and Spring Security as well, but currently I am solving task where I have to implement authentication over JWT.

I do some research and I fount 2 solutions.

1. Make authentication with Spring Security, with OAuth2 module
2. Second option is using JJWT library. The majority of guides which I found were with JJWT.

Can you tell me what is better to use and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer of this it will help you. [JWT vs OAuth authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909419/jwt-vs-oauth-authentication)
You can use OAuth2 with JWT together.

Comment: So if I am right, If I need provide authentication for another applications, something like google or fb do, then go with OAuth2, and if I just need authentication for my app using JJWT is enough?

Comment: @DenisStephanov Yes. If your not building your own Authentication you can use google or fb authentication and you just need to send the Access-token on header of your request. If you looking for login with google or fb spring has a project called spring-social. https://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-social-tutorial/