# How to create your own custom SSO (Single Sign-On) in java?

Tags: java, spring, oauth, jwt, single-sign-on

We have a application that has calls a **Authentication Service** to authenticate users using username and password (Hashing, encryption etc.) its working fine, but now we are expanding and creating few new applications and we want to use this **Authentication Service** as a **SSO**.

I have watched many tutorials but they all use some **pre-built SSO**, which in my case we can't company policy.

So in searched I found about **JWT and OAuth2**, and *spring-security out of box sso* and but don't know where to begin to build our own/custom sso and what are the pre-requisite's.

Any help will be appreciated.

I know this question is very vast, but trust me I have tried searching whole day, but can't seem to find the implementation, every where just concept is given with **pre-built Authentication Service**

Comment: https://hellokoding.com/hello-single-sign-on-sso-with-json-web-token-jwt-spring-boot/

Comment: Its a very good tutorial, I just one question which technique is more secure using JWT or OAUTH? Sorry if my question doesn't any sense. @sonus21

Comment: I would suggest giving a read on this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909419/what-are-the-main-differences-between-jwt-and-oauth-authentication