# crossdomain cookies in 2023 and authentification using JWT

Tags: cookies, jwt, microservices

I do have a problem about understanding crossdomains cookies.

I am currently working on a kind of small micro services architecture app ( I only splitted the front-end and the back-end). So I followed this tutorial :

https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/rails-session-cookies-for-api-authentication.

At first, when reading this tuto, it seemed to be a good idea to opt for cookies based authentication. Everything was working fine on development, but when I push it on production (on 2 differents domain name), thing was not working anymore..

So after a few searches on the internet, I found that modern browser tended to block crossdomain cookies. I found an article on stack overflow which redirected me to this post :

https://medium.com/@ArturoAlvarezV/use-session-cookies-to-authenticate-a-user-with-a-rails-api-backend-hosted-in-heroku-on-one-domain-f702ddf8c07

where they advise us to use a special gem. But when I read the gem doc, they said that it would become useless by 2022...

After some more searches, I found that the best way to manage it was probably to use JWT. I read few articles, and they advocate to use cookies set with httponly flag to safely store refresh tokens...

**So here is my question**: No matter which authentication system I choose, I will still need my back-end to send cookies to my front-end? Or in case of JWT, should my back-end sent refresh tokes as json and then the front-end app saves it as httponly cookies?? Or do I misunderstand something about changes in cookies management?

I know the question may seemed stupid, but more I deep into this topic, more I get confused...

Thanks

Comment: On an unrelated note. I am going through a similar issues (Backend sending refresh token as JSON and access tokens as cookies) with cookies although my problem is slightly different than yours. This [RFC8582-draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps) recommends not to use cookies for token storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your frontend (assuming is javascript based) should not be able to access your cookies.

The cookies are sent as a response from your backend. If you are getting a CORS error, it is likely that you need to whitelist the origin (your backend domain) for it to be able to send you your authentication cookies. You can take a look at this [medium article](https://medium.com/@Nicholson85/handling-cors-issues-in-your-rails-api-120dfbcb8a24) on how to do it in ruby

Httponly flag mitigates risk of client-side scripts accessing the protected cookie. You should know you can still access the cookie via your developer tools.

Having cookies stored also means that your browser automatically sends those [cookies with every request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) that can impact your performance.

This also poses a problem if you are intending to expand your MS architecture to include an API gateway that may expect the JWT token to be included in the authorisation header and not a cookie. It is something that you may want to consider as I am currently going through this issue.

If you are implementing a JWT based authentication system, I would recommend you to look into [OIDC](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/openid-connect-protocol) and its best practices.

You should also take a look at this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909419/what-are-the-main-differences-between-jwt-and-oauth-authentication?rq=1) to gain a better understanding between JWT and Oauth2 if you are intending to go for that route as well.