# is JWT an implementation of OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt

can we say that JWT is an implementation of OAuth2 ?
like for example JPA and Hibernate
JPA is a specification and hibernate is the implementation of JPA 
Thanks

Comment: and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964774/oauth-or-jwt-which-one-to-use-and-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWT means "JSON Web Token" The header contains a token what the server uses. You can generate the token with OAuth2 process. But JWT is not OAuth2 because you can't compare a token approach with a complete authentication flow. In a funny way your question is more like, is the seed a kind of strawberry?

Comment: in my opinion, technically we cannot make a difference between  OAuth2 and JWT because JWT is a Token format and OAuth2 is an authorization delegation, so these are two different things, 
as you said  is more like, is the seed a kind of strawberry